# Jquery checkbox grouping - uncheck parent when at least one sub checkbox is clicked, check parent when all are checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, checkbox

I have built a form that needs to dynamically check the input checkboxes depending on its parent. So far I have got it to select all, select none, select all children within section when parent is clicked and select none within a section when that parent is clicked again.

The problem I am having is that I want the child checkbox to make the parent be unchecked when at least one is deselected. So for example, I click the checkbox on the parent, it selects all the sub checkboxes... then I click on one of those children to deselect it but I also want the parent checkbox to know this and be deselected if if one of the children is unchecked.

I also need this to go the other way so if I check all the subs within a section (and not the parent), after the last one is checked (all of them) then the parent will get the selected status.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated as I swear I am losing hair over this!

JS fiddle address:
http://jsfiddle.net/DprEu/1/

Here is my code:

JS

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
// checkbox functions
  $('#selectAllButton').on('click', function () {
      $('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', true).closest('label').addClass('c_on');
      $('#selectAllButton').addClass('c_on');
      $('#selectNoneButton').removeClass('c_on');
  });
  $('#selectNoneButton').on('click', function () {
      $('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', false).closest('label').removeClass('c_on');
      $('#selectNoneButton').addClass('c_on');
      $('#selectAllButton').removeClass('c_on');
  });

  $('.section .section_label input').click(function () {
      var chckClass = "";
      if (!this.checked) {
          chckClass = "";
      } else {
         chckClass = "c_on"
      }
      $(this).closest('.section').find('input[type="checkbox"]').not(this).prop('checked', this.checked).closest('label').removeClass("c_on").addClass(chckClass);
  });
  $('input[type="checkbox"]').on('click', function () {
       var chckClass = "";
      if (!this.checked) {
          chckClass = "";
      } else {
         chckClass = "c_on"
      }
      $(this).closest('label').removeClass('c_on').addClass(chckClass);
  });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="document">
<div class="section inline">
    <label class="label_radio lightblue" id="selectAllButton" for="selectAll">
        <input type="radio" name="masscheck" id="selectAll" />Select all</label>
</div>
<div class="section inline">
     <label class="label_radio lightblue" id="selectNoneButton" for="selectNone">
        <input type="radio" name="masscheck" id="selectNone" />Select none</label>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>


<div class="document">
    <div class="section">
        <label class="label_check section_label blue" for="docs_1131">
            <input type="checkbox" id="docs_1131" name="docs" value="1131" />Title page</label>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="document">
    <div class="section">
        <label class="label_check section_label blue" for="docs_1118">
            <input type="checkbox" id="docs_1118" name="docs" value="1118" />
            Section 1
        </label>

        <blockquote>
            <div class="subsection">
                <label class="label_check sub_label lightblue" for="docs_1119">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="docs_1119" name="docs" value="1119" />
                    Subsection 1.1
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="subsection">
                <label class="label_check sub_label lightblue" for="docs_1120">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="docs_1120" name="docs" value="1120" />
                    Subsection 1.2
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="subsection">
                <label class="label_check sub_label lightblue" for="docs_1121">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="docs_1121" name="docs" value="1121" />
                    Subsection 1.3
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="subsection">
                <label class="label_check sub_label lightblue" for="docs_1122">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="docs_1122" name="docs" value="1122" />
                    Subsection 1.4
                </label>
            </div>
        </blockquote>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="document">
    <div class="section">
        <label class="label_check section_label blue" for="docs_1123">
            <input type="checkbox" id="docs_1123" name="docs" value="1123" />
            Section 2
        </label>

        <blockquote>
            <div class="subsection">
                <label class="label_check sub_label lightblue" for="docs_1124">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="docs_1124" name="docs" value="1124" />
                    Subsection 2.1
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="subsection">
                <label class="label_check sub_label lightblue" for="docs_1125">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="docs_1125" name="docs" value="1125" />
                    Subsection 2.2
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="subsection">
                <label class="label_check sub_label lightblue" for="docs_1126">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="docs_1126" name="docs" value="1126" />
                    Subsection 2.3
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="subsection">
                <label class="label_check sub_label lightblue" for="docs_1127">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="docs_1127" name="docs" value="1127" />
                    Subsection 2.4
                </label>
            </div>
        </blockquote>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.c_on{
    background-color:red;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var $all = $('#selectAllButton input[type="radio"]').change(function () {
        $sectionchecks.prop('checked', true).trigger('change');
        $none.closest('label').removeClass('c_on');
    });
    var $none = $('#selectNoneButton input[type="radio"]').change(function () {
        $sectionchecks.prop('checked', false).trigger('change');
        $all.closest('label').removeClass('c_on');
    });

    $('.section .section_label input').click(function () {
        $(this).closest('.section').find('.subsection input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', this.checked).trigger('change')
    });

    $('.section .subsection input').change(function () {
        var $section = $(this).closest('.section');
        var $childs = $section.find('.subsection input[type="checkbox"]');
        $section.find('.section_label input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', $childs.not(':checked').length == 0).trigger('change')
    });

    var $sectionchecks = $('.section').find('input[type="checkbox"]');
    $sectionchecks.add($none).add($all).change(function(){
        $(this).closest('label').toggleClass('c_on', this.checked);
    })
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/k63xA/)

Comment: This is great and does exactly what I need. Only problem is that it has knocked off the class change of c_on for the selected state

Comment: I have integrated your solution into mine and got it working but I am running into issues where the class name is not being applied or removed from the parent labels. Here is the JSFiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/DprEu/2/

Comment: Basically, when the top level checkbox is checked, it needs the same class applied as the subsections and will turn red to indicate the class being applied. (its becuase this will be a form that uses CSS to override the default form style so the classes are needed for this)

Answer (score 0):

If it will be aways this structure you can find you parent checkbox like this:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('click', function () {
       var chckClass = "";
      if (!this.checked) {
          chckClass = "";
      } else {
         chckClass = "c_on"
      }
      if($(this).parent().hasClass('sub_label')) { // HERE YOU KNOW IF ITS A SON OR FATHER         
         $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().find('input[type:checkbox]:first').attr('checked');
         $(this).closest('label').removeClass('c_on').addClass(chckClass);
      }
  });
```